# How I export my profile data from a firefox extension?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

How I export my profile data from an extension?
An extension I'm using isn't working properly and I'd like to export my data before reinstalling it.
It's called onetab.

The menu on the top right corner is gone, so how can I export my saved data (or tabs)?

[image: onetab firefox extension is faulty]

Answer (score 1):

Firefox plugin data is stored in `%appdata%\Roaming\Mozilla\Plugins\`. I would back-up the contents of that folder, then remove the offending preferences file.

Alternatively, add `/import-export.html` to the end of the URL you have. Export the URLs, blast the add-on, then re-add it e.g. `moz-extension://47f198f4-e5c4-407e-ae76-97625d481c7a/import-export.html`

Comment: Going to `import-export.html` doesn't work. I can't backup the contents of the entire folder because I have no way of exporting my list of URLs in onetab. But which specific file is the data for my specific extension stored?

Comment: @desbest - You could open your tabs and create a bookmark.  Alternative is to troubleshoot the icon, unless OneTab is disabled, you should be able to create a new profile and manually port the OneTab extension tab to diagnose the icon problem.

Comment: Troubleshoot the icon? Do you mean tab? How? If I view the source of the web page the data I’m looking for isn’t there.

Answer (score 1):

This are the two best sources for OneTab recovery:

- https://www.ghacks.net/2018/08/06/dont-downgrade-firefox-63/
- https://support.mozilla.org/mk/questions/1261474#answer-1229059

and script which read session datafiles:
https://www.jeffersonscher.com/ffu/scrounger.html

Comment: Although your answer may be 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...